# Copy cell C value to other sheet if Cell A = Cell B

Tags: vb.net, string, excel, vba

I am new to vb macro, what I want to do is if cell A (list) = cell b then copy the value of cell C to another sheet, once copied, if the list changes to another name, the value of cell C should be empty, but the previously copied value from cell C should be retained.

I have this code but it seems it doesn't run.

```
Sub SearchMacro()

Dim LR As Long, i As Long
With Sheets("M-List")
    LR = .Range("T" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    For i = 1 To LR
        With .Range("T" & i)
            If .Value = "JAN!D158=N2" Then
                Sheets("JAN!").Range("D158:H158").Copy Destination:=Sheets("M-List!").Range("T2")          
            End If
        End With
    Next i
End With

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question seems confusing from the beginning. If you want to compare two cells you do

`Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").Value = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B50").Value`

Your code seems a little bit odd with what you said you want to do, but here are some recommendations so you can play with it

Try .Formula instead of .Value = "JAN!D158=N2", `If .Formula = "JAN!D158=N2" Then`

Try Sheets("JAN") instead of "JAN!"

You may want to use .Value instead of .Copy

`Sheets("M-List").Range("T2").Value = Sheets("JAN!").Range("D158:H158").Value`

You may want to use variables for the row numbers D158 or T2 like `.Range("T" & var_row)`

Comment: Im sorry for the messy code, im basically new to excel-vba, what I really want to do is if Cell A = Cell B copy the value of cell C to another sheet Cell D and store it,

Comment: Well, unless you have a specific question, if this helps you find your way, please accept the answer :)

Comment: `If Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").Value = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B1").Value Then Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A1").Value = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("C1").Value`

Comment: Thanks for the response, I still got error maybe I post this on another thread - Missing ; before statement. (line 1, file "Macro")